# QtLinguist: Define a single context

Tags: qt, qml

How do I define a single context in a QtLinguist .ts file, rather than having one context per file?

I need this because I have identical strings showing up in different files for which I want the same translation (and no duplicates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From C++, you can explicitly specify the translation context on a string-by-string basis by using the static function `QCoreApplication::translate(const char* context, const char* text)` instead of the traditional `QObject::tr(const char* text)` (see this doc for more details: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#translate)

e.g.
`menuItem->setText(QCoreApplication::translate("UniversalContext", "Exit"));`

Similarly, you can specify the context in QML using the `qsTranslate(context, text)` function, a la
`Text { text: qsTranslate("UniversalContext", "hello") }`

These will all get picked up by `lupdate` as belonging to the same context (duplicate strings will only show up once in your `.ts` file)

If you have a lot of strings and it gets painful to specify the context on every call to `translate/qsTranslate`, you should be fairly simple to create a 1-arg macro (c++) or a js function (qml) as a wrapper.

Comment: thank you @dbrianj. I'm gonna try this out. Likewise, I assume I can use QT_TRANSLATION_NOOP to mark list items etc. for translation

Comment: awesome, working as expected. QT_TRANSLATION_NOOP as well. Thank you!

Comment: `you should be fairly simple to create a 1-arg macro` - this is not working.